# Can android sdk free your memory before you are done with it?

Tags: android

My app is getting crash reports on google play.  I was told that android can release your memory on you, is this really true.

I'm getting a `NullPointerException` error on the following line

```
if (butSettings.Intersect(x, y))
```

I'm assuming `butSettings` is `null`.
I'm confuse because `butsettings` is set up on the `onCreate`. It's member functions are then called on the `onUpdate` which gets called every .1 of a second.

line

```
if (butSettings.Intersect(x, y))
```

is in my `onTouch` event.  So I'm assuming `butSettings` member functions would have gotten called in the `onDraw`. So why is this truing into a `null`?? Could android being freeing it?

stack trace from google

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.fairhvaenapps.toddpuzzlefree.cMainView.onTouchEvent(cMainView.java:267)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5588)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1684)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1684)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1684)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2060)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1398)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2364)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2008)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5768)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:2911)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2485)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.processInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:852)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2494)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Android can destroy your activity at any moment, that's why you have to properly do initialization in `onCreate` and properly dispose of things in `onDestroy`. However, you will never end up with a `NullPointerException` because of this; Android will not just simply remove a reference to an object because of this. The exception you're seeing is because of some bug in your code. It has nothing to do with memory.